SVG Icons don't show after compiling / bundling with Webpack
This is my first time building a web-application, and I'm in my final steps. I'm trying to bundle the whole project with webpack, and everything seems to work, except for my SVG-Icons.
I think the problem is how webpack references the svg's in the compiled index.html.
The original index.html references the svg's like this:
<svg role="img">
   <use href="images/icons.svg#settings-icon"></use>
</svg>

The compiled index.html references the svg's like this:
<svg role="img" style="margin-bottom:-3px">
   <use href="aaf2f945f2b181c45647.svg#settings-icon"></use>
</svg>

This is my dist/ folder after compiling:
dist/
├── images/
│   └── icons.svg
├── aaf2f945f2b181c45647.svg
├── bundle.js
└── index.html

aaf2f945f2b181c45647.svg contains this:
export default "images/icons.svg";
icons.svg contains all my svg's as it should.
When I replace all "aaf2f945f2b181c45647.svg" with "images/icons.svg" in the compiled index.html, everything works fine.
The problem is that webpack seems to be trying to navigate to icons.svg via aaf2f945f2b181c45647.svg. Why does it do that? Can I somehow tell it to directly write "images/icons.svg" into the html file?
This is my webpack.config.cjs:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './frontend/src/scripts/index.ts', // Entry point of your application
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js', // Output bundle file name
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/dist'), // Output directory
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'images/',
                        publicPath: 'images/',
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './frontend/public/index.html', // Template HTML file
            filename: 'index.html', // Output HTML file name
        }),
    ],
};

This is my complete folder structure:
dist/
├── images/
│   └── icons.svg
├── aaf2f945f2b181c45647.svg
├── bundle.js
└── index.html

public/
├── images/
│   └── icons.svg
└── index.html

src/
├── scripts/
│   └── ...
└── styles/
    └── ...

I already tried using url-loader, svg-url-loader and svg-sprite-loader instead. None of them was able to display my svg's.

Why not use html-loader for handling HTML files to ensure that use tags are processed correctly and also update file-loader settings to handle SVGs correctly within HTML as below:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './frontend/src/scripts/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js', 
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/dist'), 
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                filename: 'images/[name][ext]', 
       },
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            sources: {
                                list: [
                                    '...',
                                    {
                                        tag: 'use',
                                        attribute: 'href',
                                        type: 'src',
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './frontend/public/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html', // Output HTML file name
        }),
     ],
};


Thank you so much! The changes to the .svg handling did the trick! The changes to the html-loader weren't actually necessary for me :)

Use url-loader with webpack
{ test: /.svg$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }
